# Sed wildcards- replace in the middle of certain characters

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a line like this

```
"RU_28" "CDM_279" "CDI_45"
"RU_567" "CDM_528" "CDI_10000"
```

I want to obtain the result below

```
"RU_28" "CDM_Unusued" "CDI_45"
"RU_567" "CDM_Unusued" "CDI_10000"
```

Do this for all the lines in the file

I'm using this commands:

```
sed 's/\"CDM_\w*\"/\"Unusued\"/g' File1.txt > File2.txt
```

It doesn't seem to works.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What OS and version of `sed` are you using?

Comment: SunOS 5.10 , I'm afraid I can't find the sed version

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
sed -i.bak 's/"\(CDM_\)[^"]*"/"\1Unused"/' file1.txt
```

Comment: Feel free to use `sed 's/"\(CDM_\)[^"]*"/"\1Unused"/' file1.txt > file2.txt`

Comment: If you don't want to keep CDM_ and you want substitute starting with "CDM_*" for Unusued, you don't need the brackets, do you?

Comment: I don't need to recall the marked subexpresion with \1, cheers everyone

Comment: Yes you can even do: `sed -i.bak 's/"CDM_[^"]*"/"CDM_Unused"/' file1.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually leaving "CDM_" on the right side. Your substitution says "Replace CDM_ and any number of words with Unusued." The common way to do what you actually want to do is to use parentheses around the section on the left you want to keep, and then use backreferences to indicate where they go on the right. In this case, you just need a single backreference, indicated by `\1`:

```
sed 's/"\(CDM_\)\w*"/"\1Unusued"/g' File1.txt > File2.txt
```

Note the backslashes before the parentheses on the left side; these can be omitted if using `sed` with `-r` (I think), for extended regexps, but as-is, they're necessary so `sed` knows they're not literal.

**Edit:** I've updated the command in response to the accurate comment by Birei, noting that the extraneous escapes for the double-quotes. (Note that the ones for the parentheses are still necessary).

Comment: +1 because it works but it is not necessary to escape double-quotes in an expresssion between single-quotes. Also note that `\w` is a GNU extension.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to modify my file, the file still the same, same happens with my commands. I have tried also wildcards, I noticed a change but not what I expected. sed 's/"CDM_*"/"CDM_Unusued"/'